# javafx receive image from mysql set to Image view

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have image in my mysql database and i want to receive image i can do this in java but can't in javafx .

I am using this code to receive image from database.

```
 byte[] f51 = rs.getBytes(11);
```

now i want to set it in `Image view` .

I can do this in **Java** like `img.setIcon(new ImageIcon(f51));` but this not working in **javafx**

I used the code

```
private static Image convertToJavaFXImage(byte[] raw, final int width, final int height) {
    WritableImage image = new WritableImage(width, height);
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(raw);
        BufferedImage read = ImageIO.read(bis);
        SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(read, image);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return image;
}
```

Provided by @Patrick

now it gives error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1762)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1645)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3724)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/584634336.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1757)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(SwingFXUtils.java:85)
    at stockmanagement1.RawmaterialAddController.convertToJavaFXImage(RawmaterialAddController.java:340)
    at stockmanagement1.RawmaterialAddController.tabmrel(RawmaterialAddController.java:318)
    ... 40 more
```

Help Me please.

**Updated**

wait i think there is a confusing i have posted all codes:

adding :

```
     @FXML
        private void add(ActionEvent event) {

                      String mcode=txt1.getText();
                   String mname=txt2.getText();
                   String material=txt3.getText();
                   String quantity=txt4.getText();
                   String unit=(String) com1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                   String priceper=txt5.getText();
                   String godown=(String) com2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

                   String desc=txtdexc.getText();

                byte[] buf = null; byte[] person_image5=null;
           try{
        String df = img.getText();
    File image=new File (df);
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(image);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     buf=new byte[1024];
    for(int readnum;(readnum=fis.read(buf))!=-1; ){
    bos.write(buf,0,readnum);
}
 person_image5 = bos.toByteArray();
}
   catch(Exception e){ }   
       try{
            Connection con1=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stockmanagement","root","root");
            String sql1="INSERT INTO `rawmaterial`(`Name`, `Code`, `DOC`, `Material`, `godown`, `quantity`, `unit`, `cost`, `detail`, `pic`, `user`, `lastupdated`)"
                    + "                 VALUES    ('"+mname+"','"+mcode+"','2012-12-12','"+material+"','"+godown+"','"+quantity+"','"+unit+"','"+priceper+"','"+desc+"','"+person_image5+"','','')";
            PreparedStatement stm1=(PreparedStatement) con1.prepareStatement(sql1);
            stm1.executeUpdate(sql1);   
            tabdata();
                 } 

                 catch(Exception e){
                     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
 }

    }
```

and now codes to show image.

```
        @FXML
    void tabmrel(MouseEvent event) throws IOException {
    int x0=table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
      String id=table.getItems().get(x0).getFirstName5();
              try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stockmanagement","root","root");
        String sql="Select * from rawmaterial where code='"+id+"'";
       Statement stm=(Statement) con.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs=stm.executeQuery(sql);

       if(rs.next()){
    txt1.setText(rs.getString(3));
     txt2.setText(rs.getString(2));
   txt3.setText(rs.getString(5));
    txt4.setText(rs.getString(7));
     byte[]  f51=rs.getBytes(11); 
          System.out.println(f51);

            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(f51);
            System.out.println(bis);
            BufferedImage read = ImageIO.read(bis);
            System.out.println(read);
            Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(read, null);
            imagego.setImage(image);

      com1.getSelectionModel().select(rs.getString(8));
              txt5.setText(rs.getString(9));
           com1.getSelectionModel().select(rs.getString(6));
       txtdexc.setText(rs.getString(10));

     }
     } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {

    }
  }
```

help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hej user3829658,

you can try this method:

```
private static Image convertToJavaFXImage(byte[] raw, final int width, final int height) {
        WritableImage image = new WritableImage(width, height);
        try {
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(raw);
            BufferedImage read = ImageIO.read(bis);
            image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(read, null);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return image;
    }
```

**Update**
A full working example, the only difference is, that i load my Image from the SSD and get the `bytes[]` from the `Files.readAllBytes()` Method.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();

        // replace this PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGE
        Path get = Paths.get("<PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGE>");
        byte[] readAllBytes = Files.readAllBytes(get);
        Image convertToJavaFXImage = convertToJavaFXImage(readAllBytes, 1024, 768);
        ImageView view = new ImageView(convertToJavaFXImage);
        root.getChildren().add(view);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1024, 768);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private static Image convertToJavaFXImage(byte[] raw, final int width, final int height) {
        WritableImage image = new WritableImage(width, height);
        try {
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(raw);
            BufferedImage read = ImageIO.read(bis);
            image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(read, null);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return image;
    }

}
```

Patrick

Comment: It gives an error `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1762)
javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1757)
  30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(SwingFXUtils.java:85)
 at stockmanagement1.RawmaterialAddController.convertToJavaFXImage(RawmaterialAddController.java:340)
 at stockmanagement1.RawmaterialAddController.tabmrel(RawmaterialAddController.java:318)
  40 more`

Comment: There is a NullPointerException somewhere in your RawmaterialAddController class, at line 340 or 318.. can you also add this Controller class?

Comment: lines are    `Image sds=convertToJavaFXImage(f51, 200, 200);` -318 where  f51 is byte ` byte[]  f51=rs.getBytes(11); `

Comment: I think the `BufferedImage` is null, have you checked this, e.g. add a `System.out.println(read)`  and have a look if it is null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57675/discussion-between-user3829658-and-patrick).

Comment: so what is the solution

Comment: @user3829658 I added a working example, the difference is, that i load my image from the SSD and create the `bytes[]` with Files.readAllBytes(). Does it work for you too now?

Comment: I have posted my all codes now you can understand better

Comment: @user3829658 I found a working solution, ill post it later today.

Comment: worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**FOR THE REST OF US**

There is a much simpler way to do this ...

> ```
>             String SQL = "SELECT File from SomeTable WHERE ID = ?";
>             PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
>             pstmt.setInt(1, fileID);
>             ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
>             while (rs.next()) {
>                 InputStream imageFile = rs.getBinaryStream(1);
>                 Image image = new Image(imageFile);
>                 ImageView iv = new ImageView(image);
>             }
> ```

Once you have your ImageView object populated with the image, you can set its properties and methods to your hearts desire.